# iOS VIewController for UIScrollViews content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, scrollview, subview

I have a `UIScrollView` in my app and I am adding some custom views from xib to it so you can horizontally scroll (tabbing) in `ScrollView` to change which one is shown. For now this works but I have a problem with connecting views to controllers.

I don't know how to choose structure of `ViewControllers` (how many controllers should I use, use nested controllers,...).

I have a rootView and its controller. In this rootView there is a `ScrollView` and this ScrollView contains some custom views (subviews) loaded from xib (using loadNibNamed method).

**My question is** should I use the same `ViewController` as for `rootView` also for these `subviews` in `ScrollView`? Problem is that the `ViewControllers` view property is already bind to the rootView (`super view` in `rootView`) so when I bind this view property also to subviews an error is occurred. Also if I create new controller for these subviews an error is occurred as well.

When I am loading `subviews` to the `ScrollView` with `loadNibNamed` method in `ViewController` of rootView, owner of these `subviews` is `ViewController` (owner argument of `loadNibNamed` method is set to `self`).

Can you tell me please, how should I solve this? What `controller` should I use for `subviews`, should I create new one or should I use existing one. Or should I use some nested `controller`? I am newbie in iOS development so I have a chaos in using `ViewControllers` right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't much code that is relative to controlling the sub views you could use just the root view controller. i.e A single controller for a single scene would be a good MVC approach.

If you are using it this way , don't change the view property of view controller as this messes it up for the root view - controller setup. If you just need a reference to this views you already have it with the return value of `loadNibNamed`. Also if you are setting the owner to self then create additional instance variable to hold the sub views(and not the `view` property) so that you can specify the owner from the xib itself and connect the references appropriately.

However if you have substantial business logic to be written regarding the sub views then its fine to create separate view-controllers(a single class would be fine if all the subviews behave the more or less same way if you are getting what i mean) for it. In the xib for the subviews, you can specify this class as the owner and when using `loadNibNamed:` you should create an object of the subviewcontroller class and specify this as the owner. This way you can modularize the whole thing.

Comment: In these sub views there will be only some labels and one button. I like your last advice. So I create one SubViewController for all sub views. In XIBs of all sub views I set files owner as SubViewController. Then in the root view controller I will create object of this SubViewController and this object will be owner of each sub view. But what about view property of SubViewController? I can't bind it to all sub views so it isn't neccessary to bind this property?

Comment: Not just one controller for all sub views, but one(of same class) for each sub view.If you want to to create only one view controller you can create a instance variable for each view or store the view references as an array. But this way you won't be able to use the default behavior of the view controller for the views, i.e the methods that are supposed to be automatically called for you won't be called.

Comment: And i was not talking about the number of UI objects in your sub view as a criteria to create a separate view controller. If you feel there is enough business logic (like many methods) specific to your sub view to be written then it makes sense to use a separate view controller, otherwise it would just be overkill.

Comment: This solution you just described I already had in my code but instead of making an instance variable of ViewController and setting it as a owner I set owner by string (owner:@"subViewController") not by instance variable and I was wondering why it doesn´t work :D Thank you very much, not it works!

Comment: But I have one more question. In the ScrollView I have 3 sub views but I want it to scroll horizontally (tabing). And I want to scroll sub views in a loop (infinite scrolling). So I added before first view last view and after last view first view. It looks like this: 3 1 2 3 1. When the user goes to last view (1), it jumps to regular 1 and if he goes to first view (3) it jumps to regular 3. This works but I want to know If I have to make 2 instance of view controllers 1 and 3 because they are twice in a ScrollView. I tried to do that only with one instances but first ones didn´t appear

Comment: Its not the instance of view controller that you should be worried. Its the way you access your views. (If its the same view -probably that is what's happening when you are using only one instance, you can't see it at two place at once) However without knowing what you are doing to achieve this I can't help much. But there is a apple example for the functionality that you want to achieve. Take a look here, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html.

Comment: And you can accept/upvote the answer if you think it was helpful. :)